# Excel VBA (UDF) Returns #VALUE! Due to 255 Character Limit

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am not very familiar with VBA in Excel. I need the VBA Function text value to return regardless of character limit (if a limit is required, 560 should suffice). I have read a lot of forum posts regarding the 255 character limit and wrapping text or using different strings etc, but I don't really understand how to implement that into the code I am using below.

The situation:
I have a bunch of documents (paper copies) each day which each have a 7-digit numerical ID. This is *always* 7 numerical digits long. I type the values without spaces or commas into cell B4, and then in cell B5 I am calling the function via =InsertChar(B4) which will separate each document ID (every 7 digits) with a comma. The below code I have copied from online does the job perfectly, where every 7 digits it will insert a comma, **until cell B5 exceeds 255 characters** in which case it will return "#VALUE!".

I tried formatting the cells and adding some wraptext code (which did wrap the text), but as soon as cell B5 exceeded 255 characters, it still returned "#VALUE!" instead of the numbers & commas as text.

I would be very grateful if somebody could assist. Seems like a simple fix but I am a complete newbie to VBA and don't even understand half of the code I have used. :)

**NB:** Office Excel version 2016 *and* 365.

Cell B4 (dummy data typed in manually without commas):
`1187226118437011865811187335118756231187659911875423119155451191554511915546119155471191568611915687118722611843701186581118733511875623118765991187542311915545119155451191554611915547119156861191568711915686119156871`

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit

Function InsertChar(STR As String, Optional sInsertCharacter As String = ",", Optional lSpacing As Long = 7) As String
    Dim sCharString As String
    Dim sFormatString As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim I As Long

For I = 1 To lSpacing
    sCharString = sCharString & "&"
Next I
sCharString = sCharString & sInsertCharacter

For I = 0 To Len(STR) \ lSpacing
    sFormatString = sFormatString & sCharString
Next I

sFormatString = "!" & Left(sFormatString, Len(sFormatString) - 1)

sTemp = Format(STR, sFormatString)
If Right(sTemp, 1) = "," Then sTemp = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)

InsertChar = sTemp


End Function
```

Cell B5 (**correct** result of the VBA function when **less than 255 characters**):
`1187226,1184370,1186581,1187335,1187562,3118765,9911875,4231191,5545119,1554511,9155461,1915547,1191568,1191568,1187226,1184370,1186581,1187335,1187562,1187659,1187542,1191554,1191555,1191554,1191554,1191568,1191568,1191568,1191568,1191456,1191621`

Cell B5 (**incorrect** result of the VBA function when **more than 255 characters**):
`#VALUE!`

Comment: Does the function return the correct result from the Immediate pane? With the VBA editor open, press `CTRL+G` to get to the Immediate pane. Then type `?InsertChar("1187226118437011865811187335118756231187659911875423119155451191554511915546119155471191568611915687118722611843701186581118733511875623118765991187542311915545119155451191554611915547119156861191568711915686119156871")` in a single line and press Enter (the question mark at the beginning is important.)

Comment: Also, please provide a sample where the function fails.

Comment: @ZevSpitz The sample has 217 characters and works, add additional characters to over 255 and the function fails

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59099813/111794).

Answer (score 2):

It looks the error is because of the limitation of characters `Format` function can handle.

You need to think of another approach without using `Format`. For example,

```vb
Function InsertChar(STR As String, Optional sInsertCharacter As String = ",", Optional lSpacing As Long = 7) As String

    Dim RestChars As String
    RestChars = STR

    Do While RestChars <> ""
        InsertChar = InsertChar & Left$(RestChars, lSpacing) & sInsertCharacter
        If Len(RestChars) > lSpacing Then
            RestChars = Right$(RestChars, Len(RestChars) - lSpacing)
        Else
            RestChars = ""
        End If
    Loop

    InsertChar = Left$(InsertChar, Len(InsertChar) - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This appears to be working! :) I'll be sure to look into the different syntax used to help me better understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I copied the function into the VBA editor and attempted to run from the Immediate pane. The function falls at the following line:

```
sTemp = Format(STR, sFormatString)
```

From my tests it seems that the VBA [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function ignores more than 257 characters in the format string. For example, the following expression

```
' Generates a string composed of # characters, with a length of 272
' Pass that string as a format string to the Format function
' Return the length of the formatted string
Len(Format(5, String(272, "#")))
```

returns `257`, not `272`.

When truncated to 257 characters, the generated format string from your function has a trailing comma:

```
!&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,&&&&&&&,
```

which seems to cause the problem.

---

I would suggest looping directly over the string in groups of 7 characters. Something like this:

```
Function InsertComma(s As String) As String
    Dim length As Integer
    length = Len(s)

    Dim result As String
    result = ""

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To length Step 7
        If i > 1 Then result = result & ","
        result = result & Mid(s, i, 7)
    Next

    InsertComma = result
End Function
```

Alternatively, you could use regular expressions. Add a reference to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** library (via **Tools -> References...**).

```
Function InsertCommasWithRegex(s As String) As String
    Dim re As New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "(\d{7})(?=\d)"
    re.Global = True
    InsertCommasWithRegex = re.Replace(s, "$1,")
End Function
```

An explanation of `Pattern` -- we're trying to find:

- **every group of exactly 7 (`{7}`) digits (`\d`)**
- **the group should be captured as a submatch (`(`...`)`)** -- we need this to use the `Replace` method
- **the group is followed by another digit (`\d`)** -- this excludes the last group in the string because it isn't followed by another digit
- but **the subsequent digit should not be part of this matched result (`(?=`...`)`, AKA positive lookahead)**

There are multiple matches found within the string. We want to replace each match with the captured digits followed by a comma. In regular-expression syntax, that's written as:

```
$1,
```

(NB. Note that `RegExp.Replace` method in VBA doesn't recognize `$0` as replacing with the entire match, which is why we need the capturing group; unlike, say, .NET regular expressions.)

---

VBA References:

- [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)
- [Len function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function)
- [Mid function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function)
- [String function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-function)
- [For...Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)

VBScript Regex library references (can be used from VBA):

- [Introduction to Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//6wzad2b2%28v%3dvs.85%29)
- [RegExp object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//yab2dx62%28v%3dvs.85%29)
- [Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//f97kw5ka%28v%3dvs.85%29) and [Global](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//tdte5kwf%28v%3dvs.85%29) properties
- [Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//k9z80300%28v%3dvs.85%29)
- [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/111794)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, using [`.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate):

```
Function InsertChar(rng As Range, sInsertCharacter As String, lSpacing As Long) As String
    arr = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(1:" & Len(rng.Value) / lSpacing & "), MID(" & rng.Address & ",(ROW(1:" & Len(rng.Value) / lSpacing & ")*7)-6,7),"" ""))")
    InsertChar = Join(arr, sInsertCharacter)
End Function
```

[image]

Formula in `B1`, dragged down:

```
=InsertChar(A1,",",7)
```

---

<sub>**Note1:** `.Evaluate` takes a string holding a formula to evaluate up to 255 chars. Therefor I used a range reference instead of a string reference in the function. Now the formula would evaluate to `{IF(ROW(1:31), MID($A$1,(ROW(1:31)*7)-6,7)," ")}`, where VBA recognizes that we want it to be an array formula (therefor returning an array of values).</sub>

<sub>**Note2:** We have to `TRANSPOSE` a 2D-array into a 1D-array to be able to use it in `Join`.</sub>

Comment: @b1ll3tt, has your question been answered yet by any of the answers give? If so, accept one to close the thread and upvote those who have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to have a character limit.

For your example of 7 characters

`=SplitIt(A1,",",7)`

```
Function SplitIt(s As String, sep As String, charCnt)
    Dim rSult As String, y As Long
    Dim a, b, c
    Dim Ls As String
    a = 0
    b = charCnt
    c = charCnt

    's = [A1].Value

    For y = 1 To Len(s) / c
        Ls = Mid(s, a + 1, c)
        rSult = rSult & sep & Ls
        a = a + c
    Next

    If Left(rSult, 1) = sep Then rSult = Mid(rSult, 2, Len(rSult))
    SplitIt = rSult

End Function
```